# Where is the timeline in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, blend, timeline

Is there no timeline for animating WPF things in Visual Studio 2013?
I've looked, but I don't see anything like the *Objects and Timeline panel* in Blend.

After starting with *Blend for Visual Studio 2013* and opening in VS2013 I realized that pretty much anything I wanted to do in Blend, I could do in the IDE, until this.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no timeline in Visual Studio, there has never been one.

This is a deliberate choice. Blend is the tool of choice for animations. Visual Studio for the basic authoring. Two different audiences according to Microsoft. The hard-core developer will use Visual Studio to build the skeleton UI in Visual Studio. The hard core UX designer will then add the animations and other cool effects in Blend.

If you can do both, you'll have to switch between tools.

Comment: Yes, I am doing both. I realize there wasn't a timeline in VS in the past, but based on [this](https://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/) it was my understanding that VS would support WPF editing, and Blend was kind of an orphaned child for Windows Store and phone apps. I haven't seen any clear comparison of what is possible in VS2013 verses Blend or why you need Blend, now that so much WPF editing functionality is available in VS.

Comment: Me neither. It's majorly confusing. Since Visual Studio 2012 update 2, Microsoft ships the fully functional version of Blend with Visual Studio. But it looks like they're trying to remove it completely at some point in the future...